# My Model is not running!

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm new to Blender 3D, and I'm following one tutorial step by step.

I've edited a free model form internet, made a running animation and, this animation plays fine on time line but something is wrong when I play the script in game engine.

The model is not moving and the arms are spread like wings.
I didn't make any action frame like that.

You can download the [.blend file here](http://asdfg.tistory.com/attachment/cfile29.uf@2306834D576C3E8321F4B8.blend), and you can see a [Youtube video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0ny_aH51lo)

I hope somebody can help me.

have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the youtube video. I believe the problem you are describing is this: Your model moves its arms and legs in a walk cycle, but the model does not move from the center of the grid -- there is no X or Y motion while the animation is run.

If my understanding is right, this is easy to fix: Your walk cycle animation does not include any "forward" motion in the animation. You can add this separate from the walk cycle and make them separately controlled. You could make the legs move faster (by adjusting their scale as an Action Strip, if that is how you have the walk cycle saved) and also adjust the f curve that controls forward motion (if that is what you used).... Again, there are a couple of ways to combine multiple actions...

But I think the essence of your problem is that the walk cycle itself does not include moving the model forward... (I did not download your model, as I do not recognize the download site.)

Shout if I can assist or if I misunderstood.

Comment: Really Thanks for your kind answer, regauer. And sorry to late checking your answer. Honestly said, I try to find this question, but I forgot where I wrote this question.(Because Im really new with blender). So I could read asnwer on only youtube. And, I restart from first step and, now it works. But, I still really wanna know the essential reason. You told me about "forward" motion need to be included in walk cycle animation. My character work animation is saved on NLA Editor. But do you mean I need to add my walking animation to another place?

Comment: I had 2 problems. freezing animation and diffirient animation on time line and game engine. I found to fix "freezing". Freezing is cleared  : I activate "True trigger" in Logic editor. But still remains problem no2. So I hope to hear your little more advice. Best Regards.